# Object collisions HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

I'm making a platformer game with HTML5 Canvas. I don't have a main character yet so i'm using a ball for now. I'm trying to make it so the ball can't go through the grass block. I'm using an list to hold the values of my map, then 2 if statements to turn the list's values into a map, so I don't know how to detect a collision between the ball and the grass ball, considering the grass blocks could be anywhere on the map.

My question is: How can I make a collision between the ball and the grass block without hard coding it, it needs to be fast, and if I need a library, please show an example of how to use it in my situation.

My code is here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7OJnVpBNrkDTlA0amdzMkdrRnM

Comment: You'll basically need to check if they hit theirself while the game is running

Comment: I'd suggest to use a game engine: https://html5gameengine.com/

Comment: Either you need to build your own collision system (A bit of maths, but not too hard really), or use an existing game engine. There are some good ones floating about, take a look at "Phaser", which will handle a lot more than just collision for you want to take advantage of what it can offer.

Comment: See this [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/5017/collisions-and-intersections) for collision-testing examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic solution to your problem, from which you can build upon:

https://plnkr.co/edit/5c08NrVQh44hsq1BFX9X?p=preview

**In summary:**

- I created a new multi-dimensional array called `level1CanMove` to provide a reference for where the ball can and can't travel.
- I've used the `ballLocationCol` and `ballLocationRow` values you already had in place (but commented out), to ascertain which tiles the ball is currently over.
- We then check via the new `canMoveHere` function whether the ball can pass over the current tile and reverse direction if not.

**N.B.**
If you're just undertaking this project for learning, by all means write the code for collision detection yourself. However, if not, you'll likely find it more productive, as some commenters have already suggested, to use a game engine.

Comment: I dont know what it is with me but I prefer to not use libraries when I don't have to. But I think this should work. I used to use a double array to make my maps but I started using a single array because of a class I was taking, so thanks for that!